# Any equivalent file for TestDFSIO in hadoop 2.4.0?

Tags: hadoop

I'm new to hadoop. I want to do stress/performance test on hadoop cluster. To do that, I followed the instructions given at [Hadoop benchmarking](http://www.michael-noll.com/blog/2011/04/09/benchmarking-and-stress-testing-an-hadoop-cluster-with-terasort-testdfsio-nnbench-mrbench/). The difference is that in tutorial he is talking about hadoop 0.20.0 version and I'm trying to run similar thing in hadoop 2.4.0. I understand tutorial might not work fully, as there are many changes in version. For performing IO performance test on Hadoop, in tutorial he told me to use TestDFSIO. But I can't find the same in my hadoop installation.

To find TestDFSIO, I tried following command,

```
jar tf /home/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-2.4.0-tests.jar|grep TestDFS
```

But couldn't find it. So, I assume I the filename is changed in newer version. Can somebody help in finding the new filename? or equivalent benchmarking techniques required for hadoop 2.4.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the jar which has TestDFSIO and other bench-marking classes/code. It is present in

```
/home/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient-2.4.0-tests.jar
```

Here **/home/hadoop** is my hadoop installed path. It may not be same for you.